# According to my teacher the outer for loop repeats once in this algorithm . why?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, for-loop, execution, insertion

This is the pseudocode for insertion sort. According to my teacher the for loop repeats once. Can someone explain why?

```
for i<-2,n do 
    aux<-v [i] 
    j<-i-1 
    while aux<v [j] AND j>=0 do 
        v[j+1] <-v [j] 
        j<-j-1 
    end while
    v[j+1] <-aux 
end for
```

Comment: Are you sure that was actually what the teacher said? What exactly would 'repeat once' mean here?

Comment: Well the `for` loop runs from 2 to n. What do you mean by *repeats once*? The for loop only executes once, the loop body hover is executed `n - 2 (+ 1)` times (depending on of n is inclusive or exlusive).

Comment: when analyzing the complexity of the algorithm ,  he specified how many times each line repeats . And at the first line he mentioned that the for instruction repeats once.

Comment: I was thinking he may be refering that the for instruction executes once but iterations in a loop happen n-1 times? not sure though

Comment: Have you tried asking the teacher for clarification? This seems like a communication problem, which would more likely be solved by talking with the source than by asking here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

it does not repeat once , the for loop here has one and only one condition it's n>i (or n>=i not sure xd), and i isn't modified inside the for loop , so each repetition (iteration) is equivalent to 1 , this means the number of digits for i to reach n = the number of iterations so it's (n-i) time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).